# Defining a type whose key and value are the key of a given filter and its type

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write a function that takes a specific filter `key` whose `value` is a `keyof` an `interface` that I have defined. I would like the returned result to be an `object` that has the filter `value` present as one of the `keys` and the type of that key in the interface to be the corresponding value.

I have tried juggling through combinations of typings, but I fear I do not understand typescript well enough to figure this out. Here is my implementation,

Interface

```
interface MyModel {
  a: string;
  b: number;
  c: boolean;
}
```

Function

```
function myfunction(filter: keyof MyModel): {
  date: Date;
  [key: data.filter]: typeof filter
} {
  // ...
}
```

The above function is wrong, but I hope gives off the idea of what I am trying to get at. My
workaround currently is to use `Partial<MyModel>` which works but requires null checking the value, this is illustrated below.

```
function myfunction(filter: keyof MyModel): Partial<MyModel> & {
  date: Date;
} {
  // ...
}
```

My question is, is there a way to narrow the typings in the way illustrated above?

Comment: What is `data` in `keyof data.filter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
interface MyModel {
  a: string;
  b: number;
  c: boolean;
}

function myFunction<TKey extends keyof MyModel>(filter: TKey): Pick<MyModel, TKey> & { date: Date } {
  throw new Error("Not implemented")
}

// examples of return values types:
// myFunction('a') // { a: string, date: Date }
// myFunction('b') // { b: number, date: Date }
// myFunction('c') // { c: boolean, date: Date }
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfect. Would it be possible to get this right without using generics

Comment: @AshwynHorton, I don't think so